# How do I correctly add jQuery UI widgets?

Tags: 7, javascript

Im using Drupal 7, which ships with jQuery UI. I need to have  Accordion only on the homepage. jQuery will not just let me download Accordion and then use `drupal_add_js()`.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 8):

jQuery UI Accordion is included in core, use `drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');` to add it.