# How to include a juery ui file in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, javascript

In my code for drupal 6 I had added the following js, **jquery-ui** and css files

```
 jquery_ui_add('ui.draggable');
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'ort') . '/js/jquery.alerts.css');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ort') . '/js/jquery.alerts.js');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'ort') . '/js/ort.js');
```

For drupal 7 I have to write the above code..
I have read **that drupal 7 has jquery ui as part of core** so how should add the

```
jquery_ui_add('ui.draggable'); //drupal 6
```

code given above in drupal 7 ?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3947/how-do-i-correctly-add-jquery-ui-widgets?rq=1 or http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26062/adding-jquery-ui-selectmenu-to-drupal-form?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.draggable');`